# My received data slipt in two part in socket c#

Tags: c#, sockets, byte

I have this code as a server application to receive data :

```
public AsyncCallback pfnWorkerCallBack;
private Socket m_mainSocket;
private Socket[] m_workerSocket = new Socket[25];
private int m_clientCount = 0;
public void startfun()
{
    string Camera1Port = "1001";

    int port1 = System.Convert.ToInt32(Camera1Port);

    m_mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                      SocketType.Stream,
                                      ProtocolType.Tcp);
    IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port1);
    m_mainSocket.Bind(ipLocal);
    m_mainSocket.Listen(20);
    m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
}
public void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    m_workerSocket[m_clientCount] = m_mainSocket.EndAccept(asyn);

    WaitForData(m_workerSocket[m_clientCount]);

    ++m_clientCount;

    m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null); 
}
public class SocketPacket
{
    public System.Net.Sockets.Socket m_currentSocket;
    public byte[] dataBuffer ;
}
public void WaitForData(System.Net.Sockets.Socket soc)
{

    if (pfnWorkerCallBack == null)
    {
        pfnWorkerCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
    }

    SocketPacket theSocPkt = new SocketPacket();
    theSocPkt.dataBuffer = new byte[soc.ReceiveBufferSize];
    theSocPkt.m_currentSocket = soc;

    soc.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0,
                                   theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length,
                                   SocketFlags.None,
                                   pfnWorkerCallBack,
                                   theSocPkt);
}

public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
    string res = GetParameters(socketData.dataBuffer);
    MessageBox.Show(res);   
    WaitForData(socketData.m_currentSocket);  
}
public string GetParameters(byte[] buf)
{
    string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);
    return result;
}
```

The problem is the data is breaking .I mean when i receive data from socket in first time all values are received and the messagebox show all of that.when i receive the second data ,i just receive some part of that .suppose the data is `870314854798` .I receive the data in first time correctly ,but in second i just get 3 or 4 digit of that(it is random) and the message box shows 3 or 4 digit after clicking of ok (Messagebox) the other digits are shown.why ?

i googled it  and i found this but i can't map this solution with my solution

```
    public static void Read_Callback(IAsyncResult ar){
    StateObject so = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
    Socket s = so.workSocket;

    int read = s.EndReceive(ar);

    if (read > 0) {
            so.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(so.buffer, 0, read));
            s.BeginReceive(so.buffer, 0, StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, 0, 
                                     new AsyncCallback(Async_Send_Receive.Read_Callback), so);
    }
    else{
         if (so.sb.Length > 1) {
              //All of the data has been read, so displays it to the console
              string strContent;
              strContent = so.sb.ToString();
              Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Read {0} byte from socket" + 
                               "data = {1} ", strContent.Length, strContent));
         }
         s.Close();
    }
}
```

The problem is how can i merge this solution with my code ?

Comment: Which protocol do you use? TCP or UDP?. If it is TCP, then it is normal.... You can send 3+3 bytes and get a 6 or send a 6 and get 4+2.... You should implement a custom *protocol* to receive a *packet* (eg sending the length of data beforehand, or using a seperator char etc...)

Comment: @L.B my protpcol is tcp

Comment: [Edward's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40697769/80274) already cover this pretty well, but [here is some helpful reading on the issue](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html), you need to implment some kind of message framing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your OnDataReceived method you should EndReceive to complete the operation you began like this:

```
StateObject so = (StateObject) async.AsyncState;
Socket s = so.workSocket;

int read = s.EndReceive(async); // You need to do this.
```

You should always call, as per MSDN's recommendations, the EndReceive, EndInvoke etc on any async operation. Otherwise, you may not get the exceptions either.

Comment: sorry it was typo. I made an edit, it should have been async

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Although this answer says correct things, it doesn't solve your problem... Try to send for ex, 10M data at once... You will never get it in one *READ*

Comment: Your edit does not solve the main problem, the problem is one write does not equal one read when using TCP, sends can be split apart or combined together.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain what about this one

Comment: @EhsanAkbar go read the article I linked you to in the question. That explains the problem. You will need to have multiple `Read` or `BeginRead` calls before you do your MessageBox.Show. You don't want to wait till you reach 4000, you want to wait till you have a full "message", the way you tell when you have a full message is your responsability to code on top of the TCP connection.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for the edit and you are right about one write does not equal one read.

Comment: I did not edit it, Ehsan did, and I honestly think his edit was a bad one because the code does not work, it calls `EndReceive` multiple times but never calls `BeginReceive`

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Look at the last example here, it checks if there is more data and calls beginreceive again, it keeps doing that till all has arrived. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

That's how network stack (especially TCP) works. It does not guarantee that all data sent into a socket as a single piece would be delivered to the client as a single piece. You can only expect that all data sent into a socket will be received by the client in the same order, but can't rely on how it is going to be split into chunks.

E.g. as the data travel through the network they might pass nodes that have different settings and limitations on how big the packet may be. If a packet is too large, it will be split into multiple packets of appropriate size that will be then sent to the client.

If your protocol requires that a packet is delivered from the server to the client as a single solid piece, you would have to construct your own application layer protocol to control that. This is how http works: no matter how the data representing a web page is split into TCP packets, the client receives the whole page at once.